# How to pass parameters between controller actions without using sessions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, controller, action

For example, if in my 'edit.html.erb' file I have this:

<%= form_for(@pjt_user) do |f| %>
...

```
 <%= fields_for(:new_pjt_user) do |b| %>
          <%= b.label :new_password %>
          <%= b.text_field :new_password %>
  <% end %>
```

...
<% end %>

How can I "pre-populate"/"fill" the field 'new_password' (**in** '**fields_for**(:new_pjt_user)') passing a parameter with a *render action*? I aim to avoid to store password in session.

Comment: Any reason for using `fields_for`? Why not just use `@pjt_user` directly (`form_for`) and populate the field before the render? BTW, is "pjt" short for "project" ? If so, avoid such abbreviated names!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `render :action` you have to use `render :template` so you can use the `:locals` hash:

```
render :template => "pjt_users/new", :locals => { :default_password => DEFAULT_PASSWORD }
```

and

```
<%= fields_for(:new_pjt_user) do |b| %>
  <%= b.label :new_password %>
  <%= b.text_field :new_password, :value => default_password %>
<% end %>
```